# How to populate development database in rails3 with mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

I am using mongodb and mongoid gem with rails3.x.
I want to populate the development database. Please suggest the way or available gems

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `db/seeds.rb` file to populate your development database. It's not just for SQL stuff. Have a look at http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html and use it in a way that you can populate your mongodb.

Comment: Thanks @wintermeyer I will go for it.